# Tkinter Button Align with Grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to align my tkinter button to the left, but could not find any help.

```py
addButton = Button(root,
                   text="Add Expenses",
                   bg='red',
                   fg='white',
                   command = addButtonDef,
                   font=("Arial narrow",32))
addButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Any solution on how to align it? Only using Grid?

Comment: Read about the options using [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sticky which takes in 'W' for west.

```
addButton.grid(sticky="W", row=1, column=0)
```

alternatively you can try anchor="w" in the Button widget.

```
addButton = Button(root,
                   anchor="w"...)
```